# Connection with a FTP server hangs (never ends) when retrieving more than one network packet

Tags: networking, ftp, tcpip

I have a problem with an FTP server (ftp.cluster003.ovh.net), specifically happening when I connect to it from home (whatever the client, computer or OS).

The problem does not show up when I connect to another FTP server (ftp.phpnet.org) or when I connect to ftp.cluster003.ovh.net from my office.

At home, I am connected through a Netgear D6000 DSL modem-router.

The symptoms are the following: any time I try to retrieve some data from the server, when the amount of data to retrieve does not fit in a single network packet, the transaction never ends. This happens, of course, when retrieving a file, but also simply when listing the content of a directory when there are more than roughly 20 files in the directory (the reply from the server contains the permissions and owners of the files, so each file listed corresponds to roughly 70 bytes of data).

Example of a session (under Linux):

```
% for i in `seq 1 385`;do printf "$i-";done > file1
% for i in `seq 1 395`;do printf "$i-";done > file2
% ftp ftp.cluster003.ovh.net
Connected to ftp.cluster003.ovh.net.
220-  ~~~ Welcome to OVH ~~~
220 This is a private system - No anonymous login
Name (ftp.cluster003.ovh.net:XXXXXXXX): XXXXXXXX
331 User XXXXXXXX OK. Password required
Password:
230-OK. Current restricted directory is /
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> put file1
local: file1 remote: file1
200 PORT command successful
150 Connecting to port 56721
226-File successfully transferred
226 0.087 seconds (measured here), 16.14 Kbytes per second
1432 bytes sent in 0.00 secs (24.3868 MB/s)
ftp> put file2
local: file2 remote: file2
200 PORT command successful
150 Connecting to port 39725
226-File successfully transferred
226 0.111 seconds (measured here), 12.93 Kbytes per second
1472 bytes sent in 0.00 secs (17.9975 MB/s)
ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful
150 Connecting to port 46431
drwx---r-x    2 644709     users               4 Jan  2 13:02 .
drwx---r-x    4 644709     users               8 Dec 31 12:58 ..
-rw----r--    1 644709     users            1432 Jan  2 13:02 file1
-rw----r--    1 644709     users            1472 Jan  2 13:02 file2
226-Options: -a -l
226 4 matches total
ftp> get file1
local: file1 remote: file1
200 PORT command successful
150 Connecting to port 35507
226-File successfully transferred
226 0.001 seconds (measured here), 2.71 Mbytes per second
1432 bytes received in 0.00 secs (529.3102 kB/s)
ftp> get file2
local: file2 remote: file2
200 PORT command successful
150 Connecting to port 56107
^C
receive aborted
waiting for remote to finish abort
226-File successfully transferred
226 0.000 seconds (measured here), 2.91 Mbytes per second
500 ?
```

If I do not interrupt with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, nothing happens and the server eventually times out. When observing what happens with Wireshark, one can see that file1 fits in a single packet, whereas file2 does not.

[image: file1 fits in a single frame]

[image: file2 does not]

The last packet of file2 is received but not the previous ones. This is completely deterministic. Any ideas of what causes this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Try reducing MTU on the local interface.

Comment: I changed it from 1492 to 600 (the least possible) and it did not change anything to the behavior, except that, the size of the frames being smaller, the maximum size of what I can retrieve decreases.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this problem has been reported by other people having the Netgear D6000 modem-router, for instance:

- [Here](https://community.netgear.com/t5/DSL-Modems-Routers/D6000-Disable-Port-Scan-and-DoS-Protection-but-WiFi-issues/td-p/1089123) and [here](https://community.netgear.com/t5/DSL-Modems-Routers/quot-Disable-Port-Scan-and-DoS-Protection-quot-blocks-FTP/td-p/1039519) on Netgear forums;
- [Here](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=36598) on Filezilla forums.

The solution (that worked for me as well) is to disable the "Port Scan and DoS Protection" feature of the router.